JWT Authorization in Angular with Cookie
I'm working on authorization in my angular 18 application. I can't figure out how to work with cookies. The problem is this: after entering login and password, the server returns a response where an access-token (HttpOnly) is set via the set-cookie header. How can I pass this jwt token in the authorization header in subsequent requests?
I read a lot of discussions on this topic, but I still couldn't find a solution, I would be glad for any help, thank you

how about HTTP - interceptor ?https://v17.angular.io/guide/http-interceptor-use-cases

I plan to use it to send requests. The question is not how exactly to add the token to substitute it into the request, but how to extract it from the cookie files

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
